# Grep matches only of multiple separated strings

Tags: regex, string, grep

I have a file with lines containing this format:

```
fieldA=value1, fieldB=value2, fieldC=value3, fieldD=value4, fieldE=value5
```

I am interested in fieldA, fieldB, fieldD. However, fieldC may or may not be present, therefore I cannot use something like:

```
grep "field" * | awk -F"," '{print $1, $2, $4}'
```

My end goal is to have output like this, all in one line:

```
fieldA=value1, fieldB=value2, fieldD=value4
```

I tried using `grep -E`, but it outputs those fields in different lines, and the association between the fields breaks.

```
grep -o -E "field1_=\w*|field2_=\w*|field3_=\w*"
```

Comment: are those 3 fields' name (A,B and D) fixed? or everything is dynamic?

Comment: Kent, all the fields are fixed (A, B,..D), but the values are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a `sed` solution acceptable?

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]* [^ ]*\).*\(fieldD=[^,]*\).*/\1 \2/' filename
```

Comment: Thank you this helped. I was able to come up with a similar solution with sed.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the field name of A,B,D grep and xargs could do the job. ( awk/sed could do it for sure)

```
grep -Po "fieldA=[^,]*|fieldB=[^,]*|fieldD=[^,]*" file|xargs -n3
```

that gives you:

```
fieldA=value1 fieldB=value2 fieldD=value4
```

if you want the comma in output:

```
grep -Po "fieldA=[^,]*,|fieldB=[^,]*,|fieldD=[^,]*" file|xargs -n3
```